# Using modifiers with variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, split

I'm attempting to search a string for a variable, and I want to ignore case when searching. In order to ignore case, I am using the /gi modifier. Unfortunately, since identifiers take in direct strings instead of variables, I am having trouble getting the program to actually search for my variable. So my code right now,

```
const splitText = cell.value.split(/searchTerm/gi);
```

searches for the literal word "searchTerm" instead of searching for the value of the variable. I have tried using ${} around the variable as well and it does not work. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: The [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp) `constructor` for this

```js
needle = 'mississippi'
haystack = 'oneMississippitwomiSsissippithreemissIssiPPifour'

reg = new RegExp(needle,'gi')
console.log(haystack.split(reg))
```